# How to check if a string value is in a correct time format using c++

Tags: c++11

what code can you use to make sure that time inputted is in the correct format

```
cout<<"What is the time of the event?" << endl;
cin.get();
getline(cin, eventTime);

// eventime is a string
```

example:

user input: 12:36:27 --> valid

user input: 25:60:60 --> invalid

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your assumptions of user input, for example, how would you handle trailing spaces or so.

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this:

```
bool checkIfValidTime(std::string const& input) {
    std::regex validTime("([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])");
    return std::regex_match(input, validTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the fields to integer then check they are in range?
Note that if you are doing a countdown timer 100 seconds is a reasonable request, but 1 min 100 seconds is not.